# Case in-sensitivity for Apache httpd Location directive

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I am working with a solution that requires the usage of mod_proxy_balancer and an application server that both ignores case and mixes different case combinations in URLs found in generated content. The configuration works, however I have now a new requirement that causes problems.

I should be able to create a location directive (as per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location ) and have the URL-path interpret in case insensitive mode. This requirement comes from the need to add authentication directives to the location. As you might guess, users (or the application in question) changing one letter to capital circumvents the protection instantly. The httpd runs on Unix platform so every configuration directive is apparently case sensitive by default.

Should the regular expressions in the Location directive work in this case? Could someone please show me an example of such configuration that should work?

In case a regular expression can not be forced to work case insensitively, what part of httpd's source code should I go around modifying?

Answer (score 3):

```
<LocationMatch (?i)^/yourcontextroot>
...
```

The (?i) tells the underlying PCRE to be case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks. I can't find this anywhere in the Apache documentation.